# Integral with probabilistic limit

Tags: integration

I have an integral over a constant function, but with an stochastic variable as a limit.
[image]

in this function, P and C are constant values. but D follows a probability distribution (let's say Normal or Gamma)

Can anybody help me please?

Comment: It seems to me that the integral would still just be $\frac{D^2}{2}(P - C)$.  It's just that this value is probabilistic.  So it's basically this is the value of your random variable and the probability would be given by a PDF over the values of $D$ (to calculate any kind of a probability of a certain value, you would have to integrate the PDF over a range of $D$ values).

Answer (score 0):

Because the function you are integrating isn't stochastic, you don't need to worry about anything and can just use the following property of definite integrals:

\begin{equation}\tag{1}\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\, dx=F( b)-F(a)\end{equation}

($F$ denotes the indefinite integral of $f(x)$)

All that needs to be done is to compute the indefinite integral, then evaluate $\mathrm{(1)}$ with the stochastic limits.